# Convergence of function of central limit theorem

Tags: convergence, central-limit-theorem, non-central

I have an estimator of the form:

$$\frac{\hat{\mu}-c}{\sqrt{n\hat{\sigma}^2}}$$

Where $c$ is constant, $\hat{\mu}$, is an estimate, $n$ is number of observations and $\hat{\sigma}^2$ is a variance estimate. I assume it follows a central limit theorem. I.e.

$$\frac{\hat{\mu}-c}{\sqrt{n\hat{\sigma}^2}}\rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$

As ${n\rightarrow\infty}$. Where $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is the standard normal distribution. If I instead considered the following statistic, is there anything I can say about the behaviour of the below statistic?

$$\frac{f(\hat{\mu})-f(c)}{\sqrt{n\hat{\sigma}^2}}$$

Where $f$ is a known continuous (non-random) function? Is there any form of CLT type result I could apply to the above and what conditions would be required for the above to converge in distribution?

Comment: I think you may use delta method instead of CLT.

Comment: Ah yep! Of course! This was what I was looking for - if you make this a full answer I will accept it :)

Comment: 1. Did what $\hat{\sigma}^2$ refers to change between your first formula and your second? If not, it cannot work in both cases (and shouldn't be represented by exactly the same symbol). 2. Why is $\sqrt{n}$ on the denominator? That doesn't make sense in most cases.